# Parse a Database Result Set into an Object List

Tags: java, list, jdbc, object, resultset

I am trying to get all data from a table contained in a database, and parse it into a List. I have tried a few different techniques and can't get it working. I am trying to serialize the ResultSet so I can send it over a socket. The code I have got so far is:

```
public Object readJavaObject(String query, Connection con) throws Exception
{        
    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
    //stmt.setString(1, id);
    query_results = stmt.executeQuery();
    while (query_results.next())
    {
        dataObject = query_results.getObject(1);
    }
    query_results.close();
    stmt.close();

    return dataObject;
}

public void run()
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName(dbClass);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection (dbUrl, user, pass);
        query = "SELECT * FROM Bench_table";
        dataList = (List) this.readJavaObject(query, con);
        con.close();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what code to write around `readJavaObject`. Can anyone help to point out where the issue is?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: can you tell us what is the exception ,error message around ?

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman -- I am looking to store all table data as a List instead of a ResultSet. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

1. You loop through the results but
   only return data from the last row. 
   Instead create a List in the
   readJavaObject method and add an
   element each pass through the loop.
2. Instead of getting the item in the first column, I assume you want all the data.  You are going to have to be more specific with which "get" methods you use to pull data off the ResultSet.  Possibly create a POJO to represent a row of data, then inside the loop populate it and store it in the list.
3. Assuming you use a POJO, you might want to use generics with your list to make it easier to get items out of it without having to cast.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [DbUtils](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/) (from apache-commons).

If you need a more complex solution for mapping sql results to java objects, take a look at [object-relational mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). In Java the standard is JPA (Java Persistence API), with Hibernate, EclipseLink and OpenJPA as the most famous implementors.

Comment: i've been searching for the last half hour for "pojo without hibernate" and tons of other variations, and this is the first reference I found to what I was looking for... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want to achieve, but can I introduce you to the [DAO (Data Access Object) Pattern](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/DataAccessObject.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I recently discovered the [CachedRowSet](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17824_01/dsc_docs/docs/jscreator/apis/rowset/javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet.html), which does exactly what OP needs. It *notably* allows to serialize a `ResultSet`, and to restore the original when needed.